# Angular application with custom package in package.json

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have an Angular application that has a custom package listed in its dependencies (with a `git+ssh`) URL. When I do the command `yarn install`, it pulls the files from the `git+ssh` remote URL fine and add it to the `node_modules` folder. Same when entering `yarn start`, the dev server renders the correct files.

But, when I do a `ng build --prod`, weirdly, it tries to pull the package from npmjs or any other related remote source. I cleared my package cache using yarn cache clean command and using `yarn cache list --pattern 'my-package'` there is no cached version. Did the same trick with npm.

In the custom package's `package.json`, I've removed every link to npmjs.

Anyone have experienced a similar issue ?

Comment: can you show your package json? or even better if you can share the whole project

Comment: As it turns out, the template wasn't copied in the .metadata.json file.